# a diameter-perimeter-area inequality for convex figures

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity, inequalities

Is the following inequality known? I believe it's true, but I could find no reference.

> For any convex body $C$ in the plane
>   we have
>   $$\left(4-\frac{8}{\pi}\right)area(C)\leq
> > diam(C)(per(C)-2diam(C)).$$

If true, this would be tight, with equality when $C$ is a disk. If it turns out not to be true, then it still makes sense to look for the best constant with the $area(C)$ term.

The following similar inequality $diam(C)(per(C)-2diam(C))\leq\frac{4}{\sqrt3}area(C)$ (equality when $C$ is an equilateral triangle) is definitely known and is proven [here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1929_3_46_/ASENS_1929_3_46__345_0/ASENS_1929_3_46__345_0.pdf).

Comment: The paper, "Inequalities for Convex Sets," by Scott and Awyong, *Journal of Inequalities in Pure and Applied Mathematics*, might help, although I don't see your inequality there (but maybe I missed it amidst the welter of notation).  PDF download: http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/016_99_JIPAM/016_99.pdf

Comment: You should also check the book "Geometric Inequalities" by Burago and Zalgaller. 

Comment: I had checked before both references (by Scott and Awyong and by Burago and Zalgaller), but I couldn't find what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This inequality is not true. Consider the rectangle on $\mathbb R^2$ with vertices $(\pm 1, 0)$, $(0, \pm \varepsilon)$. Then on the left you have $2\varepsilon(4-8/\pi)$ on the right you have approximatively $4\varepsilon^2$.

Comment: Your numbers don't look right to me, but this does look like a counterexample.

Comment: On second thought, this does not look like a counterexample. The left side appears to be equal to $4\epsilon(4−8/\pi)\simeq5.8\epsilon$ and the right side appears to be equal to $2\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}(4(1+\epsilon)-4\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}) \simeq 8\epsilon$. 

Comment: Sorry, there was a misprint in my answer. now  it is correct


Comment: I also called rectangle what should be called a rombus :)

Comment: Yes. I misinterpreted your answer. 

Comment: oh i see, you are right. so there is no non-trivial inequality of this type, which explains why i couldn't find it in the literature :)


Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation on Dmitri's idea that works as a counterexample: Take the rhombus with long diagonal $2$ and short diagonal $2\epsilon$. Then the area (LHS) grows like $\epsilon$, but the perimeter minus twice diameter goes like
$$4\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}-4$$
which grows like $\epsilon^2$.

The idea is that by moving out $\epsilon$ in the "center" rather than the edges will give quadratic growth of the perimeter rather than linear.

Comment: Connor, that is of course correct. In fact, I was thinking of exactly this example but for some reason (I guess to make the answer as short :) ) as possible put the vertices of the rombus in $\pm 1, \pm varepsilon$) instead of what I had in mind.

Comment: Yes, in restrospect I should have posted this as a comment on your answer- cheers!